# Manage multiple users connecting on multiple Postgis database via QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis

I have a question about QGIS projects and how to manage multiple users (fifteen users with usernames and passwords connecting to the same five databases in PostGIS).

Right now, there is one project per user and each time he opens it, she/he has to type her/his username and password five times.

Having only one project would be nice as it would make the changes and maintenance easier but using only one saved username and saved password to connect to Postgres/PostGIS is not an option since we need to know who is doing what on the database.

One solution that might work but takes a bit of time is to set one master password, fifteen basic authentification key on each computer and fifteen identical projects except each one connects to the databases using the user's key. That way, anyone can open his project on any computers and only type the master password.

Is there an easier way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: You'll just have to configure the PostgreSQL connection with basic authentication pair (user / password) and the user will enter only one password. And, you can maintain only one project with PostgreSQL tables within the connection. Just ensure that the connection name is the same.

Comment: I tried this but if I understand correctly how it works, I have to setup the same PostGIS connection for each user using each time a different username/password and loading the same layers in each of these connection. This method is not ideal given our project has about a hundred layers.

Comment: For me, you have to create a basic authentication with the same name and same ID (unlock the lock for modifying the ID and create the same one with 7 characters). You have just to create only one project with all the layers (you can use the QGIS data manager, you can add several layers at once) and deploy the same project for all your users.

Comment: Looks like it's working, I set up the same connection (name and ID) on each computer to the databases and all i have to do is adapt the username and password. Thanks.